# How to work with files in flutter on android 11? [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, file, permissions, android-11

Particually i need to scan media files. I tried to use path_provider package to get available paths, but I only got my app paths.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)** package? It supports multiple types of file such as Image, Video, Audio and even custom types giving you the file path if necessary. Like this:

[image]